# Strange behavior of block[self] with ternary operator

Tags: ruby, block, ternary-operator

I am using Ruby 2.1.1 and I have faced with strange behavior of the ruby block inside of the ternary operator. Please consider the following program:

```
module Prawn 
  class Document
    def self.generate(filename, &block)
      block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self] 
      p '---'
      block[self]
    end
  end
end

class A
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def foo
    qwe = 1
    Prawn::Document.generate("foobar") do 
      p @a
      p qwe
      p instance_variables  
    end
  end
end

A.new.foo
```

The thing, which is confusing me is Output of this program:

```
nil
1
[]
"---"
1
1
[:@a]
```

Can someone explain me why the results above the "---" are differ from the results below the "---"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the ternary operator. The arity is `0`, which is less than `1`, so you're comparing `instance_eval(&block)` (apples) and `block[self]` (oranges). You'd get the same result if you did

```
def self.generate(filename, &block)
  instance_eval(&block)
  p '---'
  block[self]
end
```

And the difference is easy to understand: the former is evaluated with `self` being a `Prawn::Document` class object, and in the latter, `self` is an instance of `A`.